# Installing Firefox on OEL (Oracle Enterprise Linux)

Tags: firefox, oracle-enterprise-linux

I am trying to install Firefox 59.0.2 on my linux server(**OEL**). But everytime I try to install firefox with command (**yum install firefox**) it installs 52.x version.

Could you please help me with the command to install firefox 59.0.2 in Oracle Enterprise Linux - 7.1

Answer (score 2):

If possible, use yum to install Firefox on Oracle Linux. Using yum you can specify the Firefox version to install. Depending on your OL version, you may or may not be able to install Firefox 59.0.2.

To find which versions are available through the yum repositories on your machine, run:

```
sudo yum --showduplicates list firefox
```

You can choose a specific version that is shown in the list. So, on my OL7 VMs I currently have Firefox 60.3.0, and can install it like this:

```
sudo yum install firefox-60.3.0
```

Note that you may need to uninstall the existing version of Firefox before installing a new one:

```
sudo yum remove firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're mentioning Enterprise, that's probably the reason why it downloads the 52.x version: it's the latest ESR (Extended Support Release). To install the latest version, you can:

1. Download the Linux archive from [the official page](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/).
2. Untar it with `tar -xjvf firefox-59.02.tar.bz2` (current release).
3. Run the `firefox` executable from the unpacked directory.

Comment: Yes. It worked only for unzipping. I tried this and also I have done the path setup too, but I am unable to create the profile. In my case I have to create the profile and the automatic process from java have to invoke that particular profile. which is not happening in my case.

Comment: What do you mean? Would you mind explaining what you're doing and the error you're receiving?